# Overlay a functioning anchor (<a>) on top of a button

Tags: html, button, anchor

I realize that this question has been asked before, but all of the answers I have found boil down to, "Don't do that. It's bad design" and do not provide an actual solution to the problem.  In my particular scenario, I don't believe this is a bad design and thought I'd try asking again.

I have a form with a number of buttons that are populated base on past user actions.  I would like a way for the user to dismiss buttons that are no longer needed.  My (failed) solution was to put a `<div><a><img></a></div>` within the button, using absolute positioning to place it in the upper right corner.  The `<img>` here being a box with an "x" in it.

The problem here is that clicking on the image triggers the button rather than following to the link that will remove the button.

**Is it possible to configure the anchor such that when it is clicked it follows its link rather than activating the button?**  I am looking for a solution that does not require javascript.

Thanks much,

mike

The html (generated by php) will look something like:

```
<form>
...
<button class='cached-action' name='resume' value='mmayer123'>
  <div class='username'>Mike Mayer</div>
  <div class='userid'>mmayer123</div>
  <div class='forget'>
    <a href='http://demo.org/mypage?forget=mmayer123'>
      <img src='img/delete.png'>
    </a>
  </div>
</button>
...
</form>
```

The actions, demo, and link url are all fictional, but hopefully convey the idea.

The corresponding css looks like:

```
button.cached-action {
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
}
button.cached-action div.action {
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:left;
  margin: 5px 8px 0 8px;
}
button.cached-action div.details {
  font-size:small;
  text-align:left;
  margin: -3px 8px 0 10px;
}
button.cached-action div.forget {
  position:absolute;
  top:5px;
  right:5px;
}
button.cached-action div.forget img {
  height:12px;
  width:12px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just style your anchor so it looks like a button?

Comment: you need to stop the event bubble of the click event on the a tag, so the click does not bubble up to the button

Comment: The HTML you show is thoroughly invalid. First, a `<div>` and `<a>` elements cannot be the child of a button element.

Comment: @Rob .  I have seen this comment made before about <div> and <a> being "invalid" and I know the W3C validator flags it as such.  But at the same time, I tried this out in Firefox, Chrome, Edge, and Safari. It renders fine in all these case.  What exactly does "invalid" mean here?

Comment: @MarianTheisen.  How do I do that **without** Javascript?  I was able to fix it using Javascript, but I need to support a no script option as well.

Comment: @DarkBee.  I'm happy with the visual appearance, it's the functionality that needs to be fixed.

Comment: @Rob, I would like to give you credit for the accepted answer. If you want to post it as an answer, I will mark it as the one that solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give Rob the credit for nudging me in the direction of the "ah-ha" moment that allowed me to fix my issue. While he did not give a suggestion of what I **should** do, his pointing out the "invalid" html I was using gave me the inspiration to rethink my approach.

Rather than including the delete link within the button itself, I created a common `<div>` container for both the button and the anchor.  I was then able to use position styling in order to get the link to overlay the button and still function as desired.